# How can I get the status of a job coded in another project in SpringBatch?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have project A and project B, both of them with Java and Spring Batch, project A and B are both  jobs.
I need to know in project B if the job of project A is running . I have tried using:

```
  Set<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
```

in project B but it only returns the job of project B.

Both projects are part of a JAVA application, but one runs in `context1/8081` and the other in `context2/8082`

Is there any way  I can do this? I don't even know if it is possible.
Thanks

Comment: jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName); this is correct usage. Did you pass correct job name to get the status??? can you share the code?

Comment: If both projects share the same database as job repository, then the job explorer should see both jobs.